# sticky header get smaller by scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, header

I have two small problems.

1. I have a sticky header and by scrolling down the header tags getting highlighted by entering a area. All the stuff works fine but I dont get the size of my header smaller by scrolling down. Can anyone help me?
2. I have two column. in the first one is a pic and in the second a text,
   by resizing between 1320px and 900px the pic is smaller then the area. Is it posible that all the area of the picture is filled out with pic? it doesnt matter if there is something cut out on the left site of the picture.

here is an example 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4b3c42dcf5453e39a191

Comment: sorry, I stopped reading the code after line 20 of 500

Comment: Can you provide us with a JSfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

1. You'll have to add a class on scrollstart:

   ```
   $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
          $('nav').addClass('active');
      } else {
          $('nav').removeClass('active');
      }
   });
   ```

and Css:

```
.nav {
   transition:0.5s height ease;
}        

nav.active {
   height:50px;
}
```

2. You'll have to add a 100% width on the img tag like this

   ```
   .header-kul-2-3 img {
       width:100%;
   }
   ```
3. There is a js error in your js change this:

   ```
   scrollPoint = $('*[data-anchor="' + scrollAnchor + '"]').offset().top - 28;
   ```

or set your data-achor on your sections instead of your P tags.

Comment: check out this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mk87ammu/6/
you'll have to edit the css is not looking perfect.